# .htaccess and .htpasswd throwing 500 internal server error

Tags: htaccess, htpasswd

I've created a .htaccess and a .htpasswd file, both using my hosting's tool, uploaded them, and I get an error when I try to view the directory. Why?

my .htaccess file:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /home/u947248131/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your .htaccess file   is it within

```
 <Directory /path/to/the/directory >
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /home/u947248131/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
</Directory>
```

More help http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html#gettingitworking

Otherwise if you can put the error log that would help